# Display characters in real mode without int 10h?

Tags: x86, operating-system, intel, bootloader, bios

Some programs on the net seem to do the same job without even using the `int` instruction, **such as writing directly to `bx800`**. In this case, how exactly does BIOS know if some texts should be written to console? Is it that the initial interrupt is guaranteed to occur? If so, exactly when, and what's the equivalent assembly line (or a combination of a interrupt vector and `ah`) that does the same job?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The BIOS services are there to abstract the hardware.
If you have sufficient knowledge of the underlying video card you can program it directly.

The VGA has been extensively documented <sup>[[1](https://01.org/sites/default/files/documentation/snb_ihd_os_vol3_part1_0.pdf)]
 [[2](http://www.osdever.net/FreeVGA/vga/vga.htm)] [[3](http://wiki.osdev.org/VGA_Hardware)]</sup>, though the topic is not easy and the learning curve is quite steep due to a general lack of a proper introduction.
An introduction that is out of topic for an answer on this site but a short version on why the BIOS can be bypassed can be presented.

The VGA card has an internal memory that is read cyclically (drawing is a cyclic business) to generate the analogue signals to drive the [CRT compatible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cathode_ray_tube) display.
If we know how to put the right data into that memory we will be able to draw a character.

Not all the addresses in the address space of the CPU are reclaimed by the system memory (subsystem), the range `0xb8000 - 0xbffff` is assigned to the VGA card internal memory - writing into that range will put data into the card's internal memory.

Knowing how to put some data into the card's memory we must still know *what* to put into it.
Luckily the VGA supports [text modes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VGA-compatible_text_mode) that allow the programmer to specify a character code instead of drawing each [glyph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glyph) pixel by pixel.
Each code (in jargon, [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) - which coincide with the code unit for the encoding used) is associated with a glyph by the means of the charset setup by IBM at the time ([CP437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437)).
Along with the code point, the programmer can specify the [character attributes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VGA-compatible_text_mode#Text_buffer) such as the foreground and background colours.

For example, once text mode is enabled, to draw a blue *A* on the first row at the first column just write:

```
mov WORD [es:0], 0941h        ;Assuming ES = 0b800h
                              ;09 = Attributes (Blue on black)
                              ;41h = Code point of the glyph A
```

Each character takes two bytes (a word), the first one is the code point, the second one is the attributes.
Due to the x86 [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Little-endian) the 41h (code point) will end at address 0 while the attributes will go at address 1.

Internally the matter is more complicated: see the [memory layout](http://wiki.osdev.org/VGA_Hardware#Video_Memory_Layout) and odd/even mode.

This is what programming the hardware effectively is: moving data into contexts of different semantics.

Comment: Great answer. Without the help of interrupts, VGA itself repeatedly checks its own memory range, and draw the whole thing again. However, I have to ask you that, what mandates `0xb8000 - 0xbffff` to be the VGA card internal memory? Is it conventional, or _de facto_ standard, or formally documented?

Comment: @Il-seobBae It's legacy. The range actually starts at 0xa0000, that's 640KiB - the max amount of RAM available for the original IBM PC.

Comment: Thank you for the info. You really know what you're doing! Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

What I'm understanding is you're having trouble writing to the screen. When in real mode, you can't really access any interrupts at all. You can only write to video memory. Here is some code I quickly typed up for you. Hopefully, this works

```
mov edi, 0xB8000        ; This will point to the location in ram (b8000 = video mem.)
mov BYTE [edi],   'H'   ; First we declar we are moving a byte, then we move 'H' into video memory.
mov BYTE [edi+1],  0Fh  ; The second byte is always color. This is White on black
mov BYTE [edi+2], 'i'   ; Next print the i
mov BYTE [edi+3],  0Fh
```

What we can see here is we first move edi (memory pointer) to the location in video memory. \

Comment: *"When in real mode, you can't really access any interrupts at all."* This is completely wrong. I'm not sure what you meant to say here...

Comment: I'm not sure why you would move a BYTE at a time instead of a WORD. And if you're using a loop, you might consider the string instructions (i.e., STOS).

Comment: Note that your code will fault. `edi` is beyond the 64KiB limit. You either need to properly use segmentation or setup an unreal mode.